# Ruby on Rails - API request to PHP with another API

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have build a own simple REST API in PHP. This API includes some other files which call some other APIs and visualize this data in HTML. I want to export the whole HTML output in my own API. Everything is working. The output as JSON is fine. I am using `ob_start()` to track all output in PHP.

Now we are calling my API in Ruby on Rails. The API code in Ruby is working fine for any other URL, however if I call my API where I use a `include` in PHP, Ruby do not get any response and keeps loading.

This is our Ruby code:

```
<% require 'uri' %>
<% require 'open-uri' %>
<% uri = URI.parse('www.test.de') %>
<% params = { :id => "1", :factor => "100" } %>
<% uri.query = URI.encode_www_form( params ) %>
<% response = uri.open.read %>
<%= response  %>
```

My PHP API uses this:

```
 ob_start();
 include './../index_api.php';
 $outputContent = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
  
 //Create JSON Array
 $jsonArray = array("content" => array("html_data" => $outputContent));
   

 echo json_encode($jsonArray);
```

My REST API response:

```
{
    "content": {
        "html_data": "<!-- Main Content -->  <div class=\"container-fluid\"> .... "
    }
}
```

When I use `include` here in PHP, the Ruby call is not working any more. If I comment it out, everything is working fine.

Comment: Did you enable proper PHP error reporting, and check the logs? Does the same request work when you make it _not_ from ruby, but somewhere else?

Comment: @04FS Yes, if I call my API from Postman, I get all the correct response. So the include and ob_start is working. However, calling it from Ruby does not work.

Comment: What about error reporting and the log? _“if I call my API from Postman, I get all the correct response […] However, calling it from Ruby does not work.”_ - well then the first suspicion would be, that you are not actually making the exact same request in both cases.

Comment: @04FS We are getting a 301 error in Ruby. We think that the redirect is not working.

Comment: 301 is not an _error_, and – what redirect? You have not shown _anything_ related to any redirect so far.

Comment: @04FS During the ob_start inside the include, I am calling another api. This url might get blocked, not sure.

Comment: You need to start making an effort here. You still have not answered my very first question, whether you have proper PHP error reporting enabled and if it logs anything. _“This url might get blocked, not sure.”_ - well then do some _debugging_ …? You have not even shown us what exactly you are doing there, so we can not possibly be any “surer” about anything here than _you_, the person who presumably wrote this, and is sitting right in front of the whole thing.

Comment: can you try adding http in your `uri = URI.parse('http://www.test.de')`